# Asynchronous glReadPixels with PBO

Tags: opengl, glreadpixels, pbo

I want to use two PBOs to read pixel in alternative way. I thought the PBO way will much faster, because glReadPixels returns immediately when using PBO, and a lot of time can be overlapped.

Strangely there seems to be not much benefit. Considering some code like:

```
    glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
    Timer t; t.start();
    glReadPixels(0,0,1024,1024,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
    t.stop(); std::cout << t.getElapsedTimeInMilliSec() << " ";

    glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, pbo);
    t.start();
    glReadPixels(0,0,1024,1024,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    t.stop(); std::cout << t.getElapsedTimeInMilliSec() << std::endl;
```

The result is

```
1.301 1.185
1.294 1.19
1.28 1.191
1.341 1.254
1.327 1.201
1.304 1.19
1.352 1.235
```

The PBO way is a little faster, but not a satisfactory **immediate-return**。

My question is:

- What is the factor affecting glReadPixels' performance? Somethimes, the cost of it reaches 10ms, but 1.3ms here.
- <del>Why **immediate-return** costs as much as 1.2ms? Is it too big or just normal?</del>

===========================================================================

According to comparison with a demo, I found two factors:

- GL_BGRA is better than GL_RGBA, 1.3ms=>1.0ms(no PBO), 1.2ms=>0.9ms(with pbo)
- glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB|GLUT_ALPHA) rather than GLUT_RGBA, 0.9ms=>0.01ms。That's the performance I want. In my system, GLUT_RGBA=GLUT_RGB=0. GLUT_ALPHA=8

Then another two questions:

- Why GL_BGRA is better than GL_RGBA? Is it the case for just specific platform or for all platforms?
- Why GLUT_ALPHA is so important that it affects PBO performance hugely?

Comment: ooo just tested this myself on my system
GLUT_RGBA 330 fps
GLUT_RGB|GLUT_ALPHA 630fps
that's an increase by a factor 2 had missed that GLUT_ALPHA was important.

Comment: For me on macOS, I had to make sure that my buffer size was a power of two! Otherwise glReadPixels with the PBO would block

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not know `glutInitDisplayMode` by heart, but this typically is because your internal and external format do not match. For example, you won't notice the asynchronous behaviour when the number of components do not match because this conversion still blocks the `glReadPixels`.

So the most likely issue is that with `glutInitDisplay(GLUT_RGBA)` you will actually create a default framebuffer with an internal format that's actually `RGB` or even `BGR`. passing the `GLUT_ALPHA` parameter is likely to make it `RGBA` or `BGRA` internally, which matches the number of components you want.

edit: I found an [nvidia document](http://http.download.nvidia.com/developer/Papers/2005/Fast_Texture_Transfers/Fast_Texture_Transfers.pdf) explaining some issues about pixel packing and performance influence.

edit2: The performance gain of `BGRA` is likely because the internal hw buffer is in `BGRA`, there's not really much more to it.

Comment: Can you get async glReadPixels() if you read DEPTH_COMPONENT instead of RGBA? Because I can't get the glReadPixels return immediately when using PBO.

Answer (score 3):

BGRA is the fastest since this is the native format on modern GPUs. RGBA, RGB and BGR need 'reformatting' during readback.